# How can I fix TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    number = None

    quit = False
    while(not quit):
        choice = getSelection()
        if(choice == 'G'): # get a number
            number = getANumber()
        elif(choice == 'S'): # current sum
            currSum(number)
        elif(choice == 'A'): # current avg
            currAvg(number)
        elif(choice == 'H'): # highest number
            currHighest(number)
        elif(choice == 'L'): # lowest number
            currLowest(number)
        elif(choice == 'Q'): # quit    
            print('Thanks for using the program!')
            quit = True
            pause()
        else:
            print('Invalid selection. Pick only from the menu.')
            pause()


def displayMenu():
    print("\n"*50, "=== The Menu ===")
    print("G] Get a number")
    print("S] Display current sum")
    print("A] Display current average")
    print("H] Display the current highest number")
    print("L] Display the current lowest number")
    print("Q] Quit")
    print("\n" * 2)

def getSelection():
    displayMenu()
    result = input("Enter your selection: ")
    return result

def getANumber():
    result = int(input("Enter a number, please: "))
    return result


def currSum(num):
    if(num is None):
        print("Go back and enter a number first...")
        pause()
        return 
    print("The current sum is: ", sum(num))
    pause()

def currAvg(num):
    if(num is None):
        print("Go back and enter a number first...")
        pause()
        return
    avg = sum(num) / len(num)
    print("The current avgerage is: ", round(avg,2) )
    pause()

def currHighest(num):
    if(num is None):
        print("Go back and enter a number first...")
        pause()
        return
    print("The current highest is: ", max(num))
    pause()

def currLowest(num):
    if(num is None):
        print("Go back and enter a number first...")
        pause()
        return
    
    print("The current lowest is: ", min(num)
    pause()

def pause():
    x = input("\npress any key to continue....\n")



main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pythonProject\week11\menuFuncc.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:\pythonProject\week11\menuFuncc.py", line 10, in main
    currSum(number)
  File "d:\pythonProject\week11\menuFuncc.py", line 51, in currSum
    print("The current sum is: ", sum(num))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I have this school coding project where I have to store an input from a user then find the sum, average, max, and min of the numbers, using this menu type program, preferably the prof wants it without using a list but I can't seem to work it without one. I have no idea how to get past this error and I've read some other posts about this `TypeError but somehow can't get past it.

Comment: probably occurs at `sum(num)`. What is this supposed to do? if you are putting a number inside

Comment: `num` is a single number.  It makes no sense to call `sum()` on a single number.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh It was supposed to sum the numbers once 'S' is typed with num storing multiple numbers in a list.

Comment: you are overwrite-ing the number all the time, it's not a list

Comment: and if you want to do this without lists (which you are supposed to), you gotta keep track of the number, sum, and also the count of numbers that were already inputed, that way you don't need to use `sum()`, `avg()` or anything like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the functions you are using such as sum() , avg() etc do not work on single integer.

> The sum() function returns a number, the sum of all items in an iterable.

To make this work you have to go a little manual on this one.

Also, knowing the fact that your professor has restricted your from using, list this means (in my opinion) that he/she also wants you to manually calculate the required stuff for the sake of enhancing your programming skills.

I have corrected your code below:

```
def main():

    global cur_sum
    global no_of_digits
    global highest_num
    global lowest_num

    cur_sum = 0
    no_of_digits = 0

    number = None

    quit = False
    while (not quit):
        choice = getSelection()
        if (choice == 'G'):  # get a number

            number = getANumber()
            no_of_digits += 1
            cur_sum += number

            if no_of_digits == 1:
                highest_num = number
                lowest_num = number
                prev_number = number

            if number > prev_number:
                highest_num = number

            elif number < prev_number:
                lowest_num = number

            prev_number = number

        elif (choice == 'S'):  # current sum
            currSum(number)
        elif(choice == 'A'): # current avg
            currAvg(number)
        elif(choice == 'H'): # highest number
            currHighest(number)
        elif(choice == 'L'): # lowest number
            currLowest(number)
        elif(choice == 'Q'): # quit
            print('Thanks for using the program!')
            quit = True
            pause()
        else:
            print('Invalid selection. Pick only from the menu.')
            pause()


def displayMenu():
    print("\n" * 50, "=== The Menu ===")
    print("G] Get a number")
    print("S] Display current sum")
    print("A] Display current average")
    print("H] Display the current highest number")
    print("L] Display the current lowest number")
    print("Q] Quit")
    print("\n" * 2)


def getSelection():
    displayMenu()
    result = input("Enter your selection: ")
    return result


def getANumber():
    result = int(input("Enter a number, please: "))
    return result


def currSum(num):
    if (num is None):
        print("Go back and enter a number first...")
        pause()

    else:
        print("The current sum is: ", cur_sum)
        pause()

def currAvg(num):
    if (num is None):
        print("Go back and enter a number first...")
        pause()
        return

    avg = cur_sum/no_of_digits

    print("The current avgerage is: ", round(avg, 2))
    pause()


def currHighest(num):
    if (num is None):
        print("Go back and enter a number first...")
        pause()

    print("The current highest is: ", highest_num)
    pause()


def currLowest(num):
    if (num is None):
        print("Go back and enter a number first...")
        pause()

    print("The current lowest is: ", lowest_num)
    pause()


def pause():
    x = input("\npress any key to continue....\n")


main()
```

Two things I did differently from you :

1. declared the variables as global before the code so that I can access them anywhere in the program.
2. manually calculated the sum , average , highest and lowest numbers.

Also your code was good overall except for the minor blunder I stated above :)

Comment: Thanks so much I didn't think about using global variables and your way really makes sense now using manual calculations!